# How to optimize (3*O(n**2)) + O(n) algorithm?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, optimization

I am trying to solve the arithmetic progression problem from USACO. Here is the problem statement.

> An arithmetic progression is a sequence of the form a, a+b, a+2b, ..., a+nb where n=0, 1, 2, 3, ... . For this problem, a is a non-negative integer and b is a positive integer.
>
> Write a program that finds all arithmetic progressions of length n in the set S of bisquares. The set of bisquares is defined as the set of all integers of the form p2 + q2 (where p and q are non-negative integers).
>
> The two lines of input are n and m, which are the length of each sequence, and the upper bound to limit the search of the bi squares respectively.

I have implemented an algorithm which correctly solves the problem, yet it takes too long. With the max constraints of n = 25 and m = 250, my program does *not* solve the problem in the 5 second time limit.

Here is the code:

```
n = 25
m = 250

bisq = set()
for i in range(m+1):
    for j in range(i,m+1):
        bisq.add(i**2+j**2)

seq = []
for b in range(1, max(bisq)):
    for a in bisq:
        x = a
        for i in range(n):
            if x not in bisq:
                break
            x += b
        else:
            seq.append((a,b))
```

The program outputs the correct answer, but it takes too long. I tried running the program with the max n/m values, and after 30 seconds, it was still going.

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I messed up the time complexity.

Comment: FWIW, `3*O(n**2)) + O(n)` is really `O(n**2)`

Comment: please quote what you copied from others. [Time Limit Exceeded on USACO Arithmetic Progressions Task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51642897/995714)

Comment: I just copied the USACO training problem statement.

Comment: This is actually `O(2m**2 * m*(m(m-1)/2) *n) = O(m**4 * n)` in worst case as your loop at the bottom is nested three times with the first loop having time complexity of `O(m**2)` as `max(bisq) = m**2 + m**2 = 2*m**2`, your second loop being also `O(m**2)` as `bisq` has m*(m(m-1)/2) elements. The third loop has worst case of `O(n)`. As the loops are nested you get `O(m**4 *n)`

Comment: I haven't worked on this problem specifically, but for some superficially similar problems it can be necessary to have a *mathematical* insight into the problem, just trying to program efficiently not be good enough. It may be that some important theorem from number theory or something will let you solve the problem via a short cut, and without it you've got little chance. So I'd try to learn about the set of bisquares and its properties, rather than just focusing on the programming side of things.

Comment: I don't know what USACO is but you copied from them and you must put what they said in block quotes like I did for you, not putting them in the same line just like that's what you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: this is not a full answer.** This is more of a general direction where to look for.

For each member of a sequence, you're looking for four parameters: two numbers to be squared and summed (`q_i` and `p_i`), and two differences to be used in the next step (`x` and `y`) such that

`q_i**2 + p_i**2 + b = (q_i + x)**2 + (p_i + y)**2`

Subject to:

- `0 <= q_i <= m`
- `0 <= p_i <= m`
- `0 <= q_i + x <= m`
- `0 <= p_i + y <= m`

There are too many unknowns so we can't get a closed form solution.

- let's fix `b`: (still too many unknowns)
- let's fix `q_i`, and also state that this is the first member of the sequence. I.e., let's start searching from `q_1 = 0`, extend as much as possible and then extract all sequences of length `n`. Still, there are too many unknowns.
- let's fix `x`: we only have `p_i` and `y` to solve for. At this point, note that the range of possible values to satisfy the equation is much smaller than full range of `0..m`. After some calculus, `b = x*(2*q_i + x) + y*(2*p_i + y)`, and there are really not many values to check.

This last step prune is what distinguishes it from the full search. If you write down this condition explicitly, you can get the range of possible `p_i` values and from that find the length of possible sequence with step `b` as a function of `q_i` and `x`. Rejecting sequences smaller than `n` should further prune the search.

This should get you from `O(m**4)` complexity to ~`O(m**2)`. It should be enough to get into the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

A couple more things that might help prune the search space:

```
b <= 2*m*m//n

a <= 2*m*m - b*n
```

An answer on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153603/diophantine-equation-a2b2-c2d2/153613#153613) says that for a number x to be a bisquare, any prime factor of x of the form 3 + 4k (e.g., 3, 7, 11, 19, ...) must have an even power.  I think this means that for any n > 3, `b` has to be even.  The first item in the sequence `a` is a bisquare, so it has an even number of factors of 3. If `b` is odd, then one of `a+1b` or `a+2b` will have an odd number of factors of 3 and therefore isn't a bisquare.